# How constant should be the software team?

Tags: team-management, resource-planning

I believe each software product should have its constant team throughout its life cycle.

What about the situation, when one of the core developer, who has been involved in project by 100%, shifts to another project. Here, assigning a new developer seems the only reasonable way to keep the project going. However, the time spent on communication and the full involvement and understanding of the code written by others arises many problems. Besides, many developers are reluctant to engage in such projects.
Another important thing is that team becomes fragmented and the team spirit starts to disappear, if team members are constantly changing.

How should PM keep its software team  or at least core members unchanged until the delivery of the project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How should PM keep its software team or at least core members
>   unchanged until the delivery of the project?

You shouldn't...nor could you.  People leave.  They die.  They get sick.  The only certain thing about your people is they are uncertain.  And your project should be planned with that in mind.  In other words, create a project capability that does not depend on an individual.  Never ever ever get dependent on an individual.

Your project capability should be established such that, if one person leaves, you can plug in another with an average set of knowledge, skills, and abilities that are required and keep the project machine running with little to no performance degradation.  And if you have degradation, you planned for it and can cope with it without any noticeable sequalae in any other areas of the project or business.  That is the job of the PM.

Answer (score 1):

This is common scenario which happens in many organization.. If you need to move a core resource from one project to another in between of project following things should be taken care ..(I am assuming that the core developer was team lead)

1. When the core developer moves knowledge transfer to new developer is more important. Try to spend some time and make the new developer understand the past, current and future of project.
2. The old developer even after moving to new project should spend time with the project and team until the new developer in comfortable handling the project.
3. Once the new developer is comfortable with team and project, the old developer can permanently move to new project.